# the case of string is modified when added in a matrix

Tags: python, string

I have the following code:

```
Matrix = [[""] for x in range(2)]

for x in range (2):
    Matrix[x] = input().title().split(" ")
print(Matrix)
```

When I run it with this input :

```
hEllo wOrld
SecoNd teST
```

I have this output :

```
[['Hello', 'World'], ['Second', 'Test']]
```

I don’t understand why the case of the letters is modified. I’d like to have this output :

```
[['hEllo', 'wOrld'], ['SecoNd', 'teST']]
```

So why the case is modified, and how can I avoid it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [string function title](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) is the one modifying the case. It is meant to do so :)

Just remove it and you should be fine:

```
Matrix = [[""] for x in range(2)]

for x in range (2):
    Matrix[x] = input().split(" ")
print(Matrix)
```

Comment: And it's a bad idea to initialize a list like that.

Answer (score 2):

function `title()` has made such changes. According to Python doc:

> str.title() Return a titlecased version of the string where words
>   start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are
>   lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shud not be using .title()

title() converts to uppercase ..

```
'test hello'.title() --> Test Hello
```